# Exporting eclipse plugin fails under Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, osx-mountain-lion, eclipse-juno

I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse Juno under Mountain Lion.

I can test my plugin without problem by doing `run as` > `Eclipse application`.

However when I try to export the plugin by doing the following action it fails.

1. Open `plugin.xml`
2. Go to the tab `Overview`
3. Select `Export Wizard`

It returns the following error:

```
/Users/luca/Documents/University/PhD/FODA/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/compile.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/luca/Documents/University/PhD/FODA/it.unibg.robotics.featuremodels.model/build.xml:31: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes does not exist.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/luca/Documents/University/PhD/FODA/it.unibg.robotics.featuremodels.model/build.xml:31: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes does not exist.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into this problem myself today. As far as I understood, it comes from the fact that recently Apple stopped maintaining their version of Java in favor of an official version for the MacOS X from Oracle. The Oracle version, however, doesn't have the same directory structure as before, and the build script generated by Eclipse assumes the old structure.

You can see many bug reports related to this. E.g.,

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371215
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378596
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385077

I heard that switching to using Java 6 would solve the issue, as MacOS X still has the Apple Java 6 installation with the old directory structure. I didn't want to go back to Java 6, so I didn't try this.

Instead, I tried creating the directory that is reported missing (i.e., `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes`), with nothing in it. Oddly, it seems to have worked.

Let me know if it works out for you as well... Future updates of Eclipse might also fix this (I updated mine today, but the problem was still there).

Comment: It seems to work :) Have you also tried to verify whether the exported plugins work correctly or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. I realized later that exporting the classes as a JAR and load them in the classpath (instead of having a plug-in) would be more practical and I ended up doing that. Let everyone know in case you run into any problems so they can see that this is not really a definitive solution. In any case, I believe soon this will be fixed by Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, instead of creating an _empty_ `Classes` directory I had to do this to make the runtime jar files available to the headless RCP build: `ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/Classes`

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Eclipse 3.8.2 and 4.3.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392434